# Call show.bs.modal event before parent event

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, stoppropagation

I have a bootstrap  button (I used bootstrap 4) that open a modal and transfer the data that in the button to the form in the modal by the function:

`$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event)`.

the button is in a div  (parent).
when I click on the button the parent event called before the child.
I don't want the parent event to be run.
I need only the popup modal to open.
when I try to open the button by onclick its call first but the data is not transfer.
this is my code example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/esty_sh/pen/Ngjoqr)

this is the html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 parent">
    I'm the parent!
    <div class="child">
      I'm the child
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"       data-whatever="@mdo" data-message="@test message" >Open modal </button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Bootstrap Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="form-control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the script

```
<script>
$(".parent").click(function(event){
  alert("Parent event");
})


/*
if I add this function I cant transfer the data that in the button
$(".child").click(function(event){
  alert("Child event");
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
})*/



$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  alert("btn event");
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
  var message = button.data('message') 
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body textarea').val(message)
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple in the parent click , check if `target` is different to the `button` with `data-target='#exampleModal'` or not , all that using the [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) jquery function like below :

```
//get reference to the button 
var $button = $("button[data-target='#exampleModal']");
$(".parent").click(function(event){
  if (!$(event.target).is($button)) { // be sur button was'nt clicked
    alert("Parent event");
  }
})
```

**[Updated Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjjbOP)**

See below working snippet :

```js
var $button = $("button[data-target='#exampleModal']");

$(".parent").click(function(event){
  if (!$(event.target).is($button)) {
    alert("Parent event");
  }
})



$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  alert("btn event");
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
  var message = button.data('message') 
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body textarea').val(message)
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}

.col-12{ background:red; height:100px;}
.child{background:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 parent">
    I'm the parent!
    <div class="child">
      I'm the child
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"       data-whatever="@mdo" data-message="@test message" >Open modal </button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Bootstrap Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="form-control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My pleasure.. :)

Comment: Thanks on the answers 
but my problem is:  in my site I need all the other child in the parent when I click on them the parent works.
and in your solution it don't work for any child.
I need the function of the parent works whene all other childs clicked.  
have a look on my  [example codepen](https://codepen.io/esty_sh/pen/qjjZee).

thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome @EstyShlomovitz ,  So please think mark the answer as resolved ✓ (left the answer )  :)

Comment: @bRIMOs I did :)

Comment: @EstyShlomovitz Thnx :) .